# Can I run a block of code at the beginning of only some tests in a class (from one place)?

Tags: c#, xunit

I'm using C# XUnit in Visual Studio 2019 and I have a test class with various tests, working with databases and a web app. I'd like to run some code that sets up specific DB tables prior running the tests and also cleans afterwards. The catch is that I need this code to run only before and after some specific tests.

- Using InLine params is not possible as these tests don't work with the same content.
- Fixtures are unusable as they work for all the tests.
- **EDIT:** The tests cannot have a separate class

The ideal case is to have something like:

```
[For tests with trait XZ]
TestInit(){RUN CODE}

[For tests with trait XZ]
TestCleanup(){RUN CODE]
```

Is this possible in XUnit or is using a class with extension methods the best possibility?

Comment: Move those specific tests into a separate test class with its own setup and teardown.

Comment: Thought of that, but not the solution I want, all of these tests belong together as they all test controls in the web app

Comment: That fact that those tests require such distinctly separate setup indicates that they have separate concerns than the other tests.

Comment: It's changing the default account language which then changes the hours format to 12Hr+AM/PM. Other tests dont need that setup and should work with default lang setup

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Test Fixtures](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context.html) in the xUnit documentation, specifically the "test class as context" paradigm.  Basically you can nest classes inside your test class that includes a constructor for pre-test setup and a Dispose method for post-test tear down.

Comment: I might not understand it correctly, but does it differ from creating a separate test class in a different file? It sort of sounds the same to me

Comment: @RegCent technically it is a separate class but that class is embedded in the main test class. Basically taking the target test methods and wrapping them in a class.

Comment: So far, this is the closest to the thing I had in mind :) I'm guessing there is no way to have what I described in the question and if someone definitely confirms this, I'll mark this as an answer